# Left hand fingering on arpeggio G-E-G-E-B-E on Piano keyboard

Tags: piano, fingering, arpeggios

I'm absolutely new to piano and really want to learn piano myself at home without teacher. I've got a new sheet for a song, and I'm trying to figure out left hand fingering for the arpeggio G-E-G-B. Currently I'm using (5, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2) but feel I'm wrong. I'm absolutely a beginner at piano, and this is somewhat silly question. Any kind help would be really appreciated.

Comment: It would help if you post an image of the arpeggio and a few notes past, including both right and left hand. The timing, the notes that come after, and the right hand's notes could affect the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Aaron, Sorry I'm wrong. actually arpeggio is G-E-G-E-B-E and A-F-A-F-C-F

Comment: And currently I'm using (5, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2) fingering. Sorry. I updated my question again @Aaron

Comment: Please add an image.

Comment: One of the things a teacher does, besides correcting issues, is to give you pieces to work on that gradually introduce new skills one by one. If you're trying to learn on your own, consider using a graduated series of books like the Alfred method or similar. The early levels of most of these should include recommended fingering.

Comment: I've voted to close this question (though chose the wrong reason). To give the best answer, it's necessary to know 1) the rhythm of the arpeggios, 2) the speed of the piece at the time of the arpeggios, 3) the octaves of the notes involved, 4) what the right hand is doing during the arpeggios. Without that information, there are too many possible answers to usefully enumerate. An image from the score would be best; a link to the score second best; the name of the composer, title of the piece, and measure number third best; text answers to the above items not ideal, but probably sufficient.

Comment: If you can't post actual notation for some reason, at least add octave numbers to letters. Did you mean G3-E3-G3-B3 or G3-E4-G3-B3 or something else?

Comment: Right now, the title and the body of your question ask for different arpreggios (GEGEBE *vs* GEGB). Could you please edit your post and clarify which one you're asking about? As others said, an image or the octave numbers will help.

Answer (score 1):

Use 5-2-1-2, where the 2 crosses over the 1 to play the B.

```
X: 1
T: Arpeggio fingering
M: none
K: none clef=bass
!5!G,,!2!E,!1!G,!2!B,
```

Answer (score 0):

G-E-G-E-B-E

The problem is that the notes aren't in close position, causing wider leaps.  This means that your hand size and shape and flexibility matter a lot.

It also matters whether you're using pedal, and how much you care about putting your thumb on downbeats.

I'm assuming you are using no pedal, and you just care about getting through the notes without big stretches.  Then I'd suggest:

G (5) - E (1) - G (4) - E (1) - B (3)* - E(1)

*might be too much of a stretch depending on your hand.